# How do I get the last prism in Mystic?

Tags: edge

Mystic has a prism towards the end of the run that is in a really hard to reach place, and I can't figure out how to get it.
I have managed to summon the bird, and I figure that it's related to getting the last prism there, but I'm lost beyond that.
Does anybody know how to get the last prism?

Comment: Hi @Jonathan, welcome to the site! We prefer that users ask one question per post, as it makes it easier for other users (and for Google) to find the questions. Given that you are asking about 2 separate levels, I'd encourage you to [edit](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/posts/75361/edit) your existing question (which you can do by clicking that link or "Edit" in the bottom left of this post) to remove one of the levels and [ask a separate question about it](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Feel free to check out our [FAQ] if you have more questions about how the site works.

Comment: Sorry about that. I've made the change and I promise to never make that mistake again.

Comment: @JonathanThiele No worries! We've all done it at some point or another. =D

Comment: @Jonathan No problem! The system here can take some getting used to if you're not familiar with it. Once you earn 20 rep, feel free to join our [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge) if you have any questions that aren't covered in the FAQ.

Answer (score 1):

So, I found out that the "last prism", the prism in the pyramid in the center of the level, isn't really the last prism in sequence, but the 4th to the last, and it is surprisingly easy to access. All you have to do is find the proper place to "fall off" of the floor (the mini-map, as always, is a great help here).
[image: The place to "fall off" to get to the pyramid.]

That bit of floor takes you to the pyramid, with the bit of floor underneath the prism there returning you to the main track. The bird that you summon (for an achievement) is not related to getting this prism.